# How to check drop menu value?

Tags: foreach

i have some problem with my code

I have a drop menu list with room numbers when i added this info to database.

but when i want edit this data i need to check all value items in drop menu list to set selected="selected

i try to use foreach to check all value if Equal to set flat_no value.

```
<select class="form-control" name="flat_no" id="flat_no">

     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>  
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>

<?php foreach ($options as $option){
 if ($flat_no == $value){

    echo 'selected="selected"';
 }
}
     ?>

</select>
```

i want check what is value in drop menu equal $flat_no then selected in php.
any help?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I found the solution and I want to share it with you.

```
For($i=1;$i<=23;$i++){
        ?>
            <option value="<?= $i; ?>" <?php if($flat_no == $i) echo("selected")?>>
                <?= $i ?>
            </option> 
        <?php } ?>
```